# Heroku fails pushing 'git@github.com:lgs/mongoid_taggable_with_context.git'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku, cloud

Heroku fails pushing is caused by the following gem in Gemfile :

gem 'mongoid_taggable_with_context', :git => 'git@github.com:lgs/mongoid_taggable_with_context.git'

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ git push heroku +master
Counting objects: 233, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (196/196), done.
Writing objects: 100% (199/199), 286.76 KiB | 62 KiB/s, done.
Total 199 (delta 160), reused 2 (delta 2)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.rc
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
       Updating git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git
       Fetching git@github.com:lgs/mongoid_taggable_with_context.git
       Host key verification failed.
       fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
       Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.com:lgs/mongoid_taggable_with_context.git' "/tmp/build_1mck6mlqu6pko/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_taggable_with_context-cf14763a075f5ec09e40c360c8537afb67040db7" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /tmp/build_1mck6mlqu6pko has failed.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:gitwatcher.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:gitwatcher.git'
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$
```

Comment: Why dont you use `gem "mongoid_taggable_with_context", "~> 0.8.1"`

Comment: @uDaY it is not working with Mongoid 3.0.1 and new Moped driver, while the other has been ported

Comment: Ok I have seen that you have made some changes to the original gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this?

`gem 'mongoid_taggable_with_context', :git => 'git://github.com/lgs/mongoid_taggable_with_context.git'`

Comment: @Luca, thank you. I was about to say to mark your answer as answer yourself. :)